# Publish multiple tables from different PostgreSQL's schemas on GeoServer

Tags: postgis, geoserver, schema-architecture

I have many tables (about 1000) in a postgis which  are seperated in four different schemas. I know that every PostGIS store must be connected with just one schema. Thus, what is the most efficient way to publish these tables from different schemas on GeoServer ?

Is it a good practice to create four PostGIS stores with the same user/password but with different schema or have I to use PostGIS JNDI connection ?
Is there another way to go ?

Comment: I don't see a problem with using four postgis stores. Will keep your geoserver stores clear.

Comment: Thank you for your response ! I' ll create four postgis stores with different schema.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its always preferable to use PostGIS JNDI for better connection pooling.But still you can make 4 stores if your geoserver will be accessed by multiple user then you can use the user roles and groups to control data access via stores and workspace. Also you have to figure out if the workspace will be same or different for all the stores. if its for one project then keep all the stores on one workspace but if each schema is for different project the its a good idea to make a separate workspace for each project. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you very much for your helpful answer. All my data is for one project and geoserver will be accessed by multiple users with different roles. So I will create four schema in one workspace. If PostGIS JNDI connection is more efficient than 4 simple postgis stores, I'll prefer the first one.

Comment: then i would suggest try and get comfortable with the geoserver user , role and group management concepts then establish architecture.